# Dynamic formatting of last modified filter in Data factory DataSet

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to set the last modified filter in a azure data factory dataset dynamically.

I'm using the following expression:

@formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-2),'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ')

[image: Data factory formatting]

I'm getting the following error:

> Activity Copy1 failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'modifiedDatetimeStart' property to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.,Source=mscorlib,'

I'm also not able to preview the data with this filter. I guess something is wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the following commands are tested & working after publish & trigger:

@utcnow()

@adddays(utcnow(),-2)

It's the preview functionality in the front end that is not able to deal with the expressions. This will hopefully be solved by Microsoft.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Adding this via dynamic content worked for me as of July 2020

Answer (score 1):

From the error message I understand that the string represenation of the date is not supported by the calander.

```
The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
```

Why do you need to format the string for the comparison?

Comment: i've tried with a lot of expressions:


@utcnow() doesn't work either. No clue what should be the right format..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, as a workaround, you could use this expression to get a rid of the extra characters in your datetime expression:

`@substring(formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-2), 'o'), 0, 23)`

I tested this with utcnow() and it should return the datetime in the desired format:

`"value": "2019-04-12T10:11:51.108Z"`

Answer (score 0):

turns out you can solve the above prepending a conversion to string to your line above, so from

```
@formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-2),'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ')
```

change it to

```
@string(formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-2),'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ'))
```

it works on my end

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem in data flow:

```
currentUTC()
```

did not work for pulling the last modified file in blob storage but

```
currentTimestamp()
```

did